# Docusign Connect Envelope status when print and upload is used

Tags: docusignapi

I have a connect endpoint created and I am trying to differentiate between a digitally signed envelope, and one where the document was downloaded and reuploaded using the Print and Sign feature.

Currently it seems that I get onSigningComplete event in both cases mentioned above when the document is submitted.

I also see that the status of the envelope gets set to Completed when I receive the connect response at my end point.

My questions are as follows:

Is this the expected behavior, or am I missing something?

Is there some flag in the envelope that indicates that a document was downloaded, signed and uploaded vs. signed digitally?  If yes, how do I get that flag in my connect end point?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/

and call endpoint

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events
```

to get list of audit events happened for that envelope, for eg: it will show you list of events for Print and Sign like:

a.     {
           "name": "Action",
           "value": "Printable Copy Delivered"
        },
        {
            "name": "Message",
            "value": "Signer1 received a printable copy of the envelope"
        }

b.      {
           "name": "Action",
           "value": "Uploaded Attachment"
        },
        {
           "name": "Message",
           "value": "Signer3 uploaded a file that contains paper with hand signature"
        }

These audit events will show if document was download, signed & uploaded vs signed digitally

Comment: I don't have the accountId or any API access.

I have a powerform url that looks like  https://demo.docusign.net/Member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=0b07e75b-8c3e-43b6-add7-b87ccf6a6d66&persistentoriginal=1 

I get a response when the user signs like
    [source] => connect, [event] => onSigningComplete, [env] => {GUID}, [pf] => {GUID}, [r] => {GUID}  then I get a larger response 20 seconds later at my connect end point, with envelope details, but no audit_events or "Printable..." anything.

Comment: In Connect, you will get DocumentStatus inside DocuSignEnvelopeInformation - > EnvelopeStatus -> DocumentStatuses, if document is Signed on Paper then you will find one name as <Name>Signed-on-Paper_<It Can be anything></Name>, So name as Signed-On-Paper will tell you that it was not electronically signed. Let me know if it works for you.